# Android Room Database: crashing on insert after adding TypeConverter to store list of objects

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

I don't get any error but during debugging my app crashes at this line:

```
 currentWeatherDao.insertWeatherData(currentWeather)
```

where

```
currentWeather = CurrentWeatherEntry(base=stations, clouds=Clouds(all=19), cod=200, coordinate=Coordinate(lat=50.0833, lon=19.9167), dt=1639359545, id=3094802, main=Main(feelsLike=-10.06, humidity=93, pressure=1023, temp=-4.69, tempMax=-0.63, tempMin=-6.89), name=Krakow, sys=Sys(country=PL, id=19912, message=0.0, sunrise=1639377067, sunset=1639406289, type=2), timezone=3600, visibility=2500, weather=[Weather(description=mist)], wind=Wind(deg=70, speed=4.02))
```

Everything was working fine till i started implementing TypeConverter to store List of objects inside my database now app crashes on insert and I can't find problem with the code.

Here is relevant code.

ENTITY:

```
const val CURRENT_WEATHER_ID = 0


@Entity(tableName = "current_weather")
data class CurrentWeatherEntry(
val base: String,
@Embedded(prefix = "clouds_")
val clouds: Clouds,
val cod: Int,
@SerializedName("coord")
@Embedded(prefix = "coordinate_")
val coordinate: Coordinate,
val dt: Int,
val id: Int,
@Embedded(prefix = "main_")
val main: Main,
val name: String,
@Embedded(prefix = "sys_")
val sys: Sys,
val timezone: Int,
val visibility: Int,
val weather: List<Weather>,
@Embedded(prefix = "wind_")
val wind: Wind
) {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
var keyId: Int = CURRENT_WEATHER_ID

constructor() :this("", Clouds(0), 0, Coordinate(0.0,0.0), 0, 0,
    Main(0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0),
    "",Sys("",0,0.0,0,0,0),0,
    0, mutableListOf(Weather("")),Wind(0,0.0))
}
```

DATABASE:

```
@Database(

entities = [CurrentWeatherEntry::class],
version = 1
)

@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class ForecastDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

abstract fun getCurrentWeatherDao() : CurrentWeatherDao

companion object {
    @Volatile private var instance: ForecastDatabase? = null
    private val STOP = Any()

    operator fun invoke(context: Context) = instance ?: synchronized(STOP){
        instance ?: createDatabase(context).also{instance = it}
    }

    private fun createDatabase(context: Context) = 
Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
    ForecastDatabase::class.java, "forecast.db")
        .build()

}

}
```

DAO:

```
@Dao
interface CurrentWeatherDao {
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertWeatherData(weatherEntry:CurrentWeatherEntry)

@Query("select * from current_weather where keyId = $CURRENT_WEATHER_ID")
fun readWeatherData(): LiveData<CurrentWeatherEntry>

}
```

CONVERTERS:

```
class Converters {

@TypeConverter
fun fromListWeatherToString(weatherList: List<Weather>):String
{
    return Gson().toJson(weatherList)
}

@TypeConverter
fun fromStringToWeatherList(weatherString: String):List<Weather>
{
    val listType: Type = object : TypeToken<List<Weather>>() {}.type

    return Gson().fromJson(weatherString,listType)
}
```

Comment: Use ArrayList instead of List in your Converters class.

Comment: Tried with ArrayList and MutableList, app still crashes on insert.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a column that is a List/Array object.

What you can do is have the column as an object that has a List/Array as a member/field.

e.g.

```
data class WeatherListHolder(
   val weatherList: List<Weather>
)
```

Then have the column in the Entity as

```
val weather: WeatherListHolder,
```

Obviously you'd need to change the constructor and type converters accordingly.

Comment: Hi, I have changed what you suggested but app still crashes on insert.